# Hystrix performance overhead

Tags: performance, hystrix

I am using Hystrix for wrapping up couple of my service calls (99 percentile of the call being ~200 ms). My hystrix configuration looks like

**- core-size : 80

- executiontimeoutinMilliSeconds : 600

- metricsRollingStatisticalWindowInMilliseconds : 10000

- metricsRollingStatisticalWindowBuckets : 10**

(Rest all are defaults.)

Have been observing a weird behaviour in my application (intermittently though). Most of the times, the service calls seem to work fine without any hystrix timeouts (only a few calls timeout in an hour or so).
 
But **occasionally**, **the hystrix timeouts do increase many-folds**.
On analysing the cause, the only thing i could get hold of was that my ***execute-latency*** in hystrix (latency for my actual business logic, within the run method in my HystrixCommand) is much muchless than the ***total-latency*** (The total time taken by hystrix right from invoking execute() on the command to getting the actual response).

**Question :**
1. Why is there such huge a difference between my execute and total latencies (execute is much lesser than total latency). What could be the possible reasons for this overhead. (PS : The qps on my server is hardly 10)
2. Is there a document related to this overhead ? How can i figure out the actual bottleneck here ?

Any leads will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We faced the exact same issue, which was solved by moving to 1.5.x

Quoting from - https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/releases/tag/v1.5.0

> Bucket rolling now happens via Rx background threads instead of unlucky Hystrix command threads. This makes command performance more predictable. User-thread latency is now practically indistinguishable from command latency.